# Dias uteis com DATADIFF

Tags: php

Bom dia, gostaria de pegar somente os dias uteis aproveitando o código abaixo, ja tentei varias formas e não consegui.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
 $result_pesquisar = "SELECT *
        FROM horascorridas JOIN departamentos ON (horascorridas.subcategoria_id=departamentos.id)
        WHERE horascorridas.categoria_id = '$id_categoria' AND horascorridas.subcategoria_id = '$id_sub_categoria' LIMIT $inicio, $qnt_result_pg";
        $resultado_pesquisar = mysqli_query($conn, $result_pesquisar);       
        while ($row_pesquisar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_pesquisar)){


        //Seta a data padrão pro php reconhecer o formato d/m/Y
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Bahia');

        //Cria a data de inicio e fim convertendo a string em formato brasileiro pro formato americano

        $data_inicio = new DateTime($row_pesquisar['created'].' '.$row_pesquisar['horainicio']);
        $data_final = new DateTime($row_pesquisar['modified'].' '.$row_pesquisar['horafinal']);


        //Pega a diferença das datas               
        $diff = $data_final->diff($data_inicio);



          echo '
            <tr class="tabela">
              <td style="text-align:center;">'.utf8_encode($row_pesquisar['usuarioNome']) .'</td>
              <td style="text-align:center;">'.utf8_encode($row_pesquisar['nome_depart']).'</td>
              <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row_pesquisar['OS'].'</td>
              <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row_pesquisar['horainicio'].'</td>
              <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row_pesquisar['horafinal'].'</td>
              <td style="text-align:center;">'.date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row_pesquisar['created'])).'</td>
              <td style="text-align:center;">'.date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row_pesquisar['modified'])).'</td>
              <td style="text-align:center;">'.($diff->h + ($diff->d * 24)) .':'. $diff->format('%I:%S').'</td>
              <td style="text-align:center;">'.$diff->format('%d').'</td>
                            <tr>';

        }
```

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss, creio que a pergunta não seja duplicada, pois o meu código é diferente da que você diz que seja semelhante.

Comment: Não é uma questão de ser códigos iguais, mas sim de soluções iguais. Você não precisa contar a quantidade de dias úteis entre as datas? Se sim, é a mesma solução. Se não, talvez eu tenha entendido errado e, talvez, seria interessante acrescentar mais detalhes na pergunta.

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss, realmente preciso contar a quantidade de dias úteis entre as datas. E desculpe a minha falta de conhecimento, mas não consegui adequar meu código ao que você propôs, poderia me ajudar?